# Error: Where does the reference to this value come from? ("System.ArgumentException: [...] doesn't have value for keyword)

Tags: c#, debugging, reference, keyword

Could you please help me fix the code below?

It runs fine in Bash but when I run a debugger in Visual Studio I get the error "System.ArgumentException: 'Connection string doesn't have value for keyword 'connectionString'.'".

So I understand that there's an issue with my reference to `connectionString` but I don't know how to fix it. I tried replacing `connectionString` with my actual connection string and it works, but I'd like to avoid adding my actual connecting string directly in my code.

I'm a beginner so I get very confused.

```
using TestAppConfig;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");

builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration("connectionString");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("TestApp:Settings"));


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

This code comes from a tutorial and in the process of running it I also ran this beforehand:

```
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:AppConfig "<my_connection_string>"
```

I'm sure this is very basic but I can't fix it :(

Thank you

Comment: Could it be that the spelling, ie case-sensitivity matters? - Can you show the valueof the connestion string (sans password) ?

Comment: Thank you TaW! Endpoint=https://my-app-config2.azconfig.io;Id=FNSr-l0-s0:+G5qw33lBTcxaCbSsMOF;Secret=(...)